# Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{Q}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{Q}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space.

Can I define $f:\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(r,q)=r+q$. whether it will work.

Comment: Vector spaces over a fixed field are isomorphic iff they have the same dimension.  What do you know about the dimensions of $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: actually here both are infinite dimensional vector space. How can apply that?

Comment: If the dimension for both is the same infinite cardinal number, they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 4):

You can't quite say that $\Bbb{R\oplus Q=R}$, because $\Bbb{R\oplus Q}$ is a vector space whose underlying set is $\Bbb{R\times Q}$. So there is no equality here.

To show isomorphism, try to calculate the dimension of both spaces over $\Bbb Q$.